# Kalman filter for tracking sinusoidal motion

Tags: python, kalman-filters

I am wanting to create a Kalman filter that can be used to track an object undergoing sinusoidal (lets assume simple harmonic) motion. I have seen many examples and implemented my own python code for a simple SUVAT equation/projectile motion case however I have been having trouble finding examples where a Kalman filter is used to track an object moving with sinusoidal motion and I have been having trouble working out how to construct the State transition matrix (commonly called `A`) and the Control matrix (commonly called `B`) to model such behaviour.

This will eventually be used to track a noisy voltage signal corresponding to the position of an oscillating object such that one can recover it's 'true' motion.

I would appreciate if someone could direct me to some useful resources where I could learn how to do this or explain how I might go about doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that the amplitude remains constant as well as the angular frequency $\omega$. The phase will be predicted using $\phi_k=\phi_{k-1} + \omega T_s$

The measurement matrix usually denoted as H and is  the Jacobian matrix or the first derivatives matrix of the model with respect to the state variables. B will be the all zeros matrix.

[image: EKF]

Comment: For this application I am just measuring the position x, how might I extract the information about Amplitude, frequency and phase from the position in real time (without fitting) such that the Kalman filter can track phase?

Comment: Assume that $x(t) = A\sin(wt+\phi)$ and follow my instructions above.  Kalman will do the "fitting" inherently.

Comment: See the image I posted.

Comment: Thanks for the picture, that helped the explanation a lot!

Comment: In this case, what would Ts be?

Comment: The sampling interval. The amount of time in seconds between measurements.

Comment: Youre right it's not. This algorithm is called an extended Kalman filter (EKF) and the Jacobian matrix is used as a first order Taylor approximation. Hence the first derivative.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it's really useful. Are there any books or literature on this that you could point me towards? I'd like to gain a deeper understanding of how to construct various Kalman filters of this kind

Comment: Kalman filter is very popular so there's plenty of books and papers. Just google it.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist sure. Please note that the Jacobian matrix is changing from iteration to iteration with the new estimates of the state variables.

Comment: @NirRegev Are you formulating it as an error-state KF? In that case your equation for $z_k$ is measuring the "delta" in position using a linearized derivative approximation, instead of the position itself.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist another point about the Jacobian. The argument (t) there should be replaced with Ts.

Comment: @AtulIngle maybe this picture will be more clear.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist if you want help with the code you can email me what you have. I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on it some more over the weekend and then I might drop you an email, I'm also working through chapters 5 and 10 of the book "Fundamentals of Kalman Filtering: A Practical Approach" at the moment, which cover use of Kalman filters to track sine waves.